# Connect client socket to a cookie

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, cookies

I am making a chat program.

I am using an Nginx server and NodeJS.

I have setup a websocket via ssl and that works fine.

I have decided to use cookies for authentication.

There are two functions which are crucial:

```
mconnection.prototype.make_server_https=function(){
console.log('Make server https');

var cthis=this;
var server_https=modules.https.createServer({
    key: this.ssl_key,
    cert:this.ssl_cert,
    ca:this.ssl_ca
    },(request,response)=>{
        console.log('### CreateServer ###');

        console.log('CreateServer, Request:');
        console.log(request);

        console.log('CreateServer, Response:');
        console.log(response);

        console.log('######');
```

and

```
mconnection.prototype.make_server_websocket=function(){
var server_websocket=new modules.ws.Server({server:this.server_https});

var cookie = require("cookie");

var cthis=this;
//whenever a new client connects with the server.
server_websocket.on('connection', function(client_socket, request){
    console.log('### On Connection ###');

    console.log('OnConnection, Client Socket:');
    console.log(client_socket);
    console.log('OnConnection, Request:');
    console.log(request);

    console.log('######');
```

If I **do** state the port number in the client url,
function make_server_https gets run and inside there i can access the cookie and set it via the response object.

but in the original url,
function make_server_websocket gets run, and there i have access to the client_socket on the server. But there it seems i **dont** have access to the cookies.

I need to client_websocket to start the connection with this given client. And I need to tie it somehow with the cookies login information.

But i never have both at the same time so i dont get how i could connect them to make the login happen.

I am probably misunderstanding something, any help in the right direction would really be appreciated.

Comment: Once you Set-Cookie than browser will send the cookie in every request.
request object should contain the cookie which should be available to you in next request.

Comment: no there is never a cookie in the request object when the url is without the port number. im doing httponly.

Comment: in onconnection i dont think i can set a cookie as i dont have a response object. and in make_server_https i cannot establish the connection for i dont have the client_socket object. It works exactly not.

Comment: your first request is `GET` for index page where you can `SET-COOKIE` then it will be available on next websocket request for that you need to serve index page from your node server and if you decide to use login system then you can `SET-COOKIE` on successfull login.

Comment: i dont quite understand. in createserver, which is called if port number is stated in url, i redirect to the original url and set cookie. yes. and after that, the cookie is accessible via the request, but only in createserver. in the on connection, the request object still does not return any cookie. also not in future requests.

Comment: its like im setting the cookie, but only if custom port number is stated in the url.

Comment: i got it. its an event called on headers, not on connection. and there i can just push onto the headers.

Comment: can you please provide me bounty if you find my answer helpful and if you like - thank you

Comment: yeah i will give the bounty out in a few days and as you are the only one who has helped me you are quite likely to get it then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it. its an event called on headers, not on connection. and there i can just push onto the headers.

Answer (score 1):

you have to serve you index page from node server using `GET` then when the request reaches backend you will have response object which can then be used to `SET-COOKIE` if not set from backend.

And after GET request is complete `COOKIE` will be added in browser, when next request is made for websocket connection `COOKIE` will be added to the request in `REQUEST HEADERS` by the browser which will be available in backend through request object.

And if you decide to use it in login system then you can `SET-COOKIE` on successfull login.